# Can you help illuminate part of this Psalm(103)?

Tags: names-of-god

Psalm 103 King James Version (KJV)

103 Bless the Lord, O my soul: and all that is within me, bless his holy name.

---

My question: Does the singer command his soul to "Bless the LORD" , or is he saying that the LORD IS the soul within him?